# How to exclude identical elements from the foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

Tell me pls, how to exclude identical elements from the foreach?

**Code:**

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users, posts 
    WHERE posts.author_id = users.id';
$rows = R::getAll($sql);
$data = R::convertToBeans('posts',$rows);

foreach ($data as $element) {
    echo $element->login . '<br/>' . $element->name . '<br/><br/>';
}
```

**Result:**

mail_1@test.com

Post1

mail_1@test.com

Post2

mail_2@test.com

Post3

mail_3@test.com

Post5

mail_2@test.com

Post4

**As needed:**

mail_1@test.com

Post1

Post2

mail_2@test.com

Post3

Post4

mail_3@test.com

Post5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing all details, this approach might not work in all cases (but it works on this one):

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a->login, $b->login); });

foreach ($data as $i => $element) {
    if ($i === 0 || $data[$i-1]->login !== $element->login) {
        echo $element->login . '<br/><br/>';
    }

    echo $element->name . '<br/><br/>';
}
```

What this does is it sorts by `login` field in ascending order and then iterating through sorted array. If the previous element's `login` field is different than current's, then it means we have a new login value.

Answer (score 0):

You can first group the content of array by `login` and the loop through the grouped array to display:

```
$groupedData = [];

foreach ($data as $element) {
    $groupedData[$element->login][] = $element->name;
}

foreach ($groupedData as $login => $names) {
    echo $login . '<br/>' . join('<br/>', $names) . '<br/><br/>';
}
```

What is good is you can actually use the groupedData array elsewhere if you need it.